# I have a problem JSON stringify with circular structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

i try to json strigify and parse after circular structure. I want to pass to all my website my variable socket when i use socket io.
In React, it's easy but the project is old and they not use React for all the project.

I use flatted library, and it's work very good for stringify but i don't get my original element. When i parse it, i get an object

```
const mySocket = io("monsite:1234");
const stringigy = JSON.stringify(mySocket);
localStorage.setItem("io",mySocket);
```

don't work because circular structure.

With Flatted

```
const mySocket = io("monsite:1234");
const stringigy = Flatted.stringify(mySocket);
localStorage.setItem("io",mySocket);
```

work but when i parse, i don't get the original value

```
socket = Flatted.parse(getIo);
```

EDIT: 
[image: Flatted]

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's inherently impossible to serialize a data structure that contains cycles to a format like JSON.  If you flatten it, you're of course *changing* the structure.

Comment: why are you trying to serialize a socket?

Comment: because i want pass the socket that i create in all my website

Answer (score 5):

A **Circular structure** is when a property of the object is the object itself directly (`a -> a`) or indirectly (`a -> b -> a`).

To avoid the error message, tell `JSON.stringify` what to do with circular reference.

The second parameter to `stringify` is a *filter function*. Here it simply converts the referred object to its ID, but you are free to do whatever you like to break the circular reference.

For example, if you have a person pointing to another person ("father"), which may (or may not) point to the original person, do the following:

```
JSON.stringify( that.person, function( key, value) {
  if( key == 'father') { return value.id;}
  else {return value;}
})
```

Comment: @Khol if you want to re-create the circular references, you'll have to come up with some annotation scheme to indicate what has to be done. It is *impossible* to serialize to JSON a circular structure, so any serialization inherently must *change* the structure.

Comment: If you don't know the readability of the stringified object, I suggest using [CircularJSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json#circularjson).

Comment: But In fact, why do you want to stringify a socket?

Comment: i want to stringify it to put it in local storage like i say in my thread. I want my variable pass in all my website.

Comment: i use flatted, the new version of CircularJSON.  i will update my thread with picture what i get when i parse after stringify